# InfoWindow - Google map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I try to add infowindows for all my markers. But I add only one InfoWindow for last marker.
Can you help me?

```
for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+i+'bla-bla-bla</div>';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: contentString
    });
    var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(events[i][1], events[i][2]),
       map: map,
       title: events[i][0]
     });
     newMarker.categorysassasas = 2;
     newMarker.category = events[i][3];
     markers.push(newMarker);
     google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,newMarker);
     });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Google Maps infowindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381355/multiple-google-maps-infowindow)

Comment: Very weird, the  code seems to be correct. I can't solve your problem, just give you a suggestion: remove all unuseful stuff and simplify the code (e.g. give contentString the value "hello") and remove the categories (newMarker.category)

Answer (score -1):

found a similar solution to your question in this stackoverflow: [Trying to bind multiple InfoWindows to multiple Markers on a Google Map and failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357323/trying-to-bind-multiple-infowindows-to-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-and-fail)

Essentially all you'll have to do is wrap your addlistener function within another function to create a closure for your marker variable - so that it is bound to the infowindow. In your case, I believe you'll have to add the listenMarker function outside of your init() and pass in the variable for marker and infowindow, like so..

```
function listenMarker (marker, info)
{
  // so marker is associated with the closure created for the listenMarker function call
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    info.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

and then in your for loop where you call the addlistener event, replace that with:

```
listenMarker(newMarker, infowindow);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: re-edited my entire answer instead of adding another one, let me know if this helps

Comment: can you paste me your code and show me how you're doing it? you should also omit newMarker.categorysassasas = 2; from your code

Comment: I found the example. http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map1.html   . But if i change the script, for example -  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(43.65654,-79.90138); 
      var marker = createMarker(point,'<div style="width:240px">Some stuff to display in the First Info Window. With a <a href="http://www.econym.demon.co.uk">Link<\/a> to Mike Williams&apos; home page<\/div>')
   }  the script doesn't work.

Comment: are you also including the createMarker function in your script? you can just create markers using the `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    title:"enter text"
});` initialization. You can bind your info window to the marker in this for loop as well, by calling the listenMarker function i explained earlier.

Comment: also, just thought I'd point out that your for loop will display 5 markers in the same position (because your point variable is not changing).