# Google Maps API - How can you show or open more than one InfoWindow?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple Google Maps infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381355/multiple-google-maps-infowindow)

I would like to open 2 or more info windows at the same time, not sure if this is possible?

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381355/multiple-google-maps-infowindow? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Google Maps API v3 and not just [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com), as is implied by your tags (though you really should add the google-maps-api-3 tag to the post), nothing prevents you from having multiple infowindows open at the same time.  You have to write your code to avoid that.